# CodeIgniter does not like special charecter slug for posts in a blog

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, slug

I am making a simple blog in CodeIgiter framework. I can create posts and when a post is created the slug is saved in the database. The slug is the same as the title of the post but what if the post is in a special charecter? For example the title of the post is "Ķas-noķika" and when I press read more a link shows me the slug like this - `http://localhost/CodeIgniteBlog/posts/Ķas-noķika`. In the database the slug is the same as in the link but it does not fetch the post instead it shows me the 404 message. So I am thinking of converting the url slug from `Ķas-noķika` to `Kas-nokika` in hopes that it would work. How do I do such a thing in CodeIgniter? Do I have to change config.php or add a function?

here is the function that creates the post:

```
public function create_post(){
        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));

        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'body' => $this->input->post('body')
        );

        return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `convert_accented_characters()` , but first you need to load the "text" helper.
Here's an example:

```
    echo convert_accented_characters("Ķas-noķika"); //Output Kas-nokika
```

More info can be founded on the documentation link:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html#convert_accented_characters

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was looking for. The built in function easily creates a slug that is acceptable to CodeIgniter for fetching data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

go to config/config.php

find and update with this

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-';

Comment: But this is already the default config. II have changed this part of the code to different permitted uri chars but nothing seems to work.